# php append string variables to another

Tags: php

I have string something like `A - Z`, `Artists & Makers` which is returned from foreach loop.

**Output like:**

> In the Press
>
> A - Z
>
> Artists & Makers

Main objective is to remove the whitespaces and replace with `-` and convert to lowercase, which I have done like below:

```
$post = <!--returned from foreach the output given above-->

$postvalue= = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($post));   //condition 1
```

Now i need to do all the replacements like below and the changes should be in single variable called `$postvalue`

```
$azpostvalue= str_replace("A - Z", "a-z", $post);  //condition 2
$artistspostvalue= str_replace("Artists & Makers", "artists-makers", $post);   //condition 3  
$spacepostvalue= str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($postvalue));
```

Intention is to str_replace all caps, extra spaces and replace with lowercase, especially for `A - Z`, `(space)&(space)` which i need to get output like `a-z` and `artists-makers`.

SO basically all these changes(ie conditions 1,2,3) should be $postvalue in one line.

But unable to do them in single line

Comment: `str_replace("a - z", "a-z", $postvalue)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're overcomplicating it. Just use:

```
$postvalue = str_replace("a - z", "a-z", $postvalue);
```

Note that you already converted it to lowercase, so you should be matching `a` and `z`, not `A` and `Z`.

Other than that your code would have worked, but it would replace letters that aren't part of `a - z` -- any `a` at the end of a word would have the space removed after it.

Comment: should rather be `$postvalue = str_replace("a - z", "a-z", $postvalue);`

Comment: @Barmar, can u please tell how to append all the str_replace in one string from my updated question

Comment: You shouldn't completely change your question like this. Please revert your edits and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you replace the hyphens with white space first, and then do the rest of the white space replacements. If I understand what your asking then this should work:

```
$post = <!--returned from foreach the output given above-->

$postvalue = str_replace(' - ', '-', strtolower($post));
$postvalue = str_replace(' ', '-', $postvalue);
```